# Order two lists in mysql before combining, or after in code?

Tags: java, mysql, performance, sql-order-by

Say I have two lists with values that are returned from a mysql query (For purposes of this question I'll just show them as initialized here so it's easier to see the contents of the lists):

```
List<String> databaseResultsA =  new ArrayList<>(); 
databaseResultsA.add("6"); 
databaseResultsA.add("7");
databaseResultsA.add("9");


List<String> databaseResultsB = new ArrayList<>();
databaseResultsB.add("4");
databaseResultsB.add("8");
databaseResultsB.add("2");
```

In reality, databaseResultsA is ordered using MySQL ORDER BY ASC, whereas databaseResultsB is not ordered. Also of note, databaseResultsB is the result of a query on a separate database from databaseResultsA.

I need the two lists combined and ordered ascending, so I do this in the code after:

```
List<String> combinedResults = Stream.concat(databaseResultsA.stream(), databaseResultsB.stream()).sorted().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

My reasoning for sorting databaseResultsA is that I am expecting databaseResultsA to need to return results more frequently than databaseResultsB; therefore, if databaseResultsB is empty, then there would be less sorting in the code (databaseResultsA could be empty and databaseResultsB could have results, but I am not expecting that to happen as frequently as the other way around).

My question is, does my logic sound reasonable? Or would it be better to sort both lists in MySQL and then sort in code? I'm guessing this is something one should judge on a case by case basis, but just wondering if there is a rule of thumb for this.

Comment: [Please update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66717279/edit) with sample data. Post along your MySQL query and illustrate what you're trying to do. At the moment your question is not easy to imagine and I'm afraid it will just be voted to close.

Comment: Thanks, I added some more information. I didn't include the MySQL queries as they didn't seem key to the question

Comment: I may understand what you mean but I think it still unclear. Let's assume your MySQL query is like `SELECT * FROM tableA ORDER BY columnA ASC`; no other condition but `ORDER BY`. My question is, what is the column used for the sorting? What is the significance of using that particular column for the sorting? And why bother doing the sorting in the first place when you are going to re-sort them in the java code anyway?

Comment: Why does it matter whether they are sorted?  What do you do with the two lists?  Are you merging them?  Or what?

Comment: @RickJames Yes, thanks for clarifying, the example above is simplified but I'm merging the results - they're results from two separate databases that need to be shown in search results in a type ahead search bar, and they need to be in ascending order. So the solution below makes sense to me, to sort in the queries and then do a merge-sort for better performance

Comment: @moesyzlack23 - By "separate database" do you mean a single MySQL instance?  Or the necessity of having two different connections?  For a single instance, use the "db.tbl" syntax to reach for both table in a single connection and single query.  Otherwise, the second advice of user2023577 is wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the queries were distinct but on the same DB, I would not even combine in code. I would use UNION DISTINCT then ORDER BY. The server is very likely to sort faster than any java code AND you may even save some bandwidth by not downloading duplicate rows.

Now that you edited the question and say that the DBs are distinct, I would still sort both queries with ORDER BY. Then I would use a merge-sort given that you have 2 sorted inputs. I would NOT use streams to loose that precious pre-sort state only to have to resort again.

Merging 2 sorted iterators in a destination list is quite easy to write by yourself too.

Comment: Thanks - I'm realizing I was not completely clear on this; I added more details above - the two separate lists databaseResultsA and databaseResultsB are from two separate databases, so that's why I was combining them in code

Comment: Just to flesh out the comment above: It seems my options are to 1. order both in MySQL, then combine and order again in code. 2. Don't order in MySQL and just order in code. 3. The way I proposed. 4. Don't order databaseResultsA in MySQL and order databaseResultsB in MySQL, then order both in code. I'm wondering which is recommended based on performance/maintainability

Comment: Thanks for the updated explanation. Not having to resort and just use a merge sort does sound more performant. I'll look into the best way to merge 2 sorted iterators into a destination list, and also dig a little into what the streams solution is doing under the covers when the results of both the queries are sorted.

Comment: The question is tagged `[mysql]`, so let's not assume too much smarts in the Optimizer.  I don't believe `ORDER BY` is ever implemented by "merge".  `UNION DISTINCT` forces a temp table to be generated.  Ditto for `UNION ALL + ORDER BY`.  (I don't know whether `UNION DISTINCT + ORDER BY` takes 1 or 2 temp tables.)